# Implementing Stripe on Web: Uncaught ReferenceError: StripeCheckout is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement Stripe payments in my web app.  However, when using the sample code I am getting the following javascript error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: StripeCheckout is not defined

The code is like so:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>

    <script>
      Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_HnjFihOWwYTWnnsTLnZTmbgv');

      var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
        key: 'pk_test_HnjFihOWwYTWnnsTLnZTmbgv',
        image: '/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
        token: function(token) {
          // Use the token to create the charge with a server-side script.
          // You can access the token ID with `token.id`
        }
      });

      $('#customButton').on('click', function(e) {
        // Open Checkout with further options
        handler.open({
          name: 'Demo Site',
          description: '2 widgets',
          amount: 2000
        });
        e.preventDefault();
      });

      // Close Checkout on page navigation
      $(window).on('popstate', function() {
        handler.close();
      });
    </script>
```

Any idea why I'm getting the error?  Thank you.

Comment: Well to answer your question, you're getting the error because the global `StripeCheckout` does not exist in the js file `https://js.stripe.com/v2/`.

Comment: https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js

Comment: It looks like you've kind of crammed part of the Stripe.js example into the regular Checkout example. If you go back and look back and the example for Checkout, you'll see it loads a different script and doesn't have a `Stripe.setPublishableKey` line.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

StripeCheckout is built on top of Stripe. You need to include the js file that defines StripeCheckout.

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
```

See the documentation here:
https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom

Answer (score 3):

The publishable key line should only be executed once the checkout.js file has been downloaded and your javascript file is compiled, for my project this works

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/">

$(function(){

  Stripe.setPublishableKey('<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:PUBLISHABLE_KEY] %>');

});

</script>
```

To test this open a console using developer tools in your browser and after the page has loaded, paste $('#payment-form') if the console returns a reference to the form in your page then its working.

I have put this in the form page in my app and it solved this error, when it was included in my javascript file even wrapped in the on ready event it caused the same error as you experienced